# AUCTeX: Command 'reftex-cleveref-cref' not recognized before 'reftex-reference' is run

Tags: latex, auctex, reftex-mode

I have a strange behavior in AUCTeX with RefTeX: the command 'reftex-reference' (`C-c )`) needs to be run before the command 'reftex-cleveref-cref' gets recognized, on a newly-started emacs session.

In other words, the command 'reftex-cleveref-cref' looks non-existing if I did not run any 'reftex-reference' yet.

What would be the explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reftex-cleveref-cref` is defined on the fly in `reftex-ref.el` from the contents of  `reftex-ref-style-alist`.  No autoload is associated with it.  So it is defined only when `reftex-ref.el` is loaded which, in turn, is provoked by the autoload cookie on `reftex-reference`.

Comment: So I guess one should find a means to autoload `reftex-ref.el` for `reftex-cleveref-cref` to be automatically available. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Something like `(autoload 'reftex-cleveref-cref "reftex-ref" nil t)` in yr init should do the job.